# Need help analyzing Big-0 Complexity for these for loops

Tags: big-o

I need to analyze the O-Notation complexity of the following code. I think I have some idea, but need some help. Do my O-Notations for each loop correct?

```
 int sum = 0;
 for (int i = 1; i <= n*2; i++ )   //N operations, ignore the multiplication by 2
   sum++;
```

O(N)

```
 int sum = 0;
 for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++)     //N operations
   for ( int j = n; j > 0; j /= 2) //N operations, ignore division by constant?
     sum++;
```

O(N^2)

```
       int sum = 0;
       for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++)       //N ops
          for ( int j = i; j <= n; j += 2) // N ops
             sum++;
```

O(N^2)

```
   int sum = 0;
   for ( int i = 1; i <= n * n; i++) // N * N ops
       for ( int j = 1; j < i; j++ ) // N opts
       sum++;
```

O(N^3)

Answer (score 0):

1. You iterate through `2*N` elements, so its `O(2N) = O(N)`
2. You iterate through `N` elements and in each iteration, you go through `logN` elements, so its `O(N*logN)` - this time its different from `1.`, because you divide the counter `j`, not the limiting variable `N`, so , that means, if `N` is `20`, you get this:

   - `first iteration: j = 20`
   - `second iteration: j = 10`
   - `third iteration: j = 5`
   - `fourth iteration j = 2`
   - `fifth iteration j = 1`

so its `log(20) = 4.something`, and that means `5` iterations... 
So, it depends where is calculation perform, either in limiting factor or iteration calculation...

3. This is `O(N^2)`, because you have for loop with n iterations, and in each iteration you have `n/2` iterations, so its `O(N * N / 2) = O(N^2)`
4. In first loop you have `N*N` iterations. In each iteration you have to go to `i`, which depends on `n`, so you have:

   - `i=1 => no iteration in inner for loop`
   - `i=2 => 1 iteration`
   - `i=3 => 2 iterations`
   - `i=4 => 3 iterations`
   - `...`
   - `i=n*n => n*n - 1 iterations`

Sum of it is:

```
0+1+2+3+...+n*n-1 = 2+3+...n*n = 1+2+3+...+m-1(where m is n*n) = m*(m+1)/2 - m
```

So its: `O(M^2) = O(N^4)`